# How to check if particular element in an array has duplicate?

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6

There is a lot of examples that illustrate how to find duplicates in an array, but I can't find the simple one that checks if particular element has duplicate. Therefore, the array of strings is input and the output is Boolean that tells us if particular element has duplicate or not.

For example:

```
array = ['name1', 'name2', 'name3', 'name2']
```

I need a function that returns "false" if element in an array is not unique, and "true" if it is.

Comment: Is it possible to add code?

Comment: I've updated my original post.

Comment: What should it return if element is not found?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```js
const isUnique = (arr, x) => arr.filter(v => v === x).length <= 1

const x = [1, 2, 3, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
console.log(isUnique(x, 3), isUnique(x, 5))
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is a sample code , with which you can identify whether a particular element is duplicated in an array or not

```
const beasts = ["ant", "bison", "camel", "duck", "bison"];

const searchKey = "ant";
let index = beasts.indexOf(searchKey);
let isDuplicate = false;

if (index == -1) {
  console.log("Element not present in array");
} else {
  index = beasts.indexOf(searchKey, index + 1);
    if (index > -1) {
      isDuplicate = true;
    }
}

console.log(isDuplicate);
```

## Solution 2
Convert array to set.
Set removes all duplicate records

```
array = ["name1", "name2", "name3", "name2"];

let set = new Set(array);

if (array.lenght === set.size) {
  console.log("Unique array items");
} else {
  console.log("Not unique array");
}
```

You can modify the code as per your needs.

Comment: Why the `while` loop?  It seems as soon as you get the second `indexOf()` match, you know it's not unique and you're done.  You don't need to keep going after the second match.

Comment: @jfriend00 makes sense. Updated the code accordingly.

Comment: @tesicg please check solution 2. If it helps

Comment: I don't think the second one is what the OP is looking for.  They want to know if a specific item is unique in the array or not.

Answer (score 0):

How do you think about this?

```js
function isUnique(arr) {
  const hash = {}
  
  for(const item of arr) {
    hash[item] = (hash[item] || 0) + 1
    if(hash[item] > 1) {
      return false
    }
  }
  
  return true
}

console.log(isUnique(['item1', 'item2', 'item1']))
console.log(isUnique(['item1', 'item2', 'item3']))
```

Comment: It's ok, but I don't need to check if array is unique as a whole. I need to check if every element in array is unique.

Comment: This isn't really what the OP asked.  They're only looking to see if one particular value in the array is unique or not.

Answer (score 0):

Try this. I hope this the solution you are trying to solve.

```js
array1 = ['name1', 'name2', 'name3', 'name2'];
array2 = ['name1', 'name2', 'name3', 'name4'];
console.log(isUnique(array1));
console.log(isUnique(array2));


function isUnique(array) {
    var valuesSoFar = [];
    for (var i = 0; i < array.length; ++i) {
        var value = array[i];
        if (valuesSoFar.indexOf(value) !== -1) {
            return false;
        }
        valuesSoFar.push(value);
    }
    return true;
}
```

Comment: It's ok, but I don't need to check if array is unique as a whole. I need to check if every element in array is unique.

Comment: @tesicg can you please be more specific to your problem?